# MYSQL ORDER BY Performance

Tags: mysql, index, order-by

We have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
 PROJECT.PROJECTID, REQUEST.REQUESTID,
 SAMPLE.SAMPLEID,SAMPLE.OTHERSAMPLEID, 
 ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2.SAMPLEID 
FROM 
 ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2,
 PROJECT,
 SAMPLE,
 REQUEST, 
 ANCESTORS A1, 
 ANCESTORS A2, 
 ANCESTORS A3 
WHERE (
 ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2.RECORDID = A1.RECORDID AND 
 A1.ANCESTORID = SAMPLE.RECORDID AND 
 SAMPLE.RECORDID = A2.RECORDID AND 
 A2.ANCESTORID = REQUEST.RECORDID AND 
 REQUEST.RECORDID = A3.RECORDID AND 
 A3.ANCESTORID = PROJECT.RECORDID) 
AND  (
 (((ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2.RecordId > 0) AND  
  ((SAMPLE.EXEMPLARSAMPLETYPE LIKE 'DNA') AND  
  (REQUEST.RecordId > 0))) 
 AND  (PROJECT.RecordId > 0))
) 
ORDER BY SAMPLE.RECORDID LIMIT 0,501;
```

The `RecordId` column on all the tables is indexed as is `AncestorId`.  No other columns are indexed.  Here is what makes no sense.  When i have the query as above, it takes 130 seconds to run on our machines here.  The `ORDER BY` is what takes all the time since if I remove it the query runs instantly.  But what is weirder is if I change to the `ORDER BY` to use a non-indexed column like `SAMPLE.SAMPLEID`, it also comes back instantly.

So when I run this wanting to `ORDER BY` an indexed field it is MUCH slower than ordering by a non-indexed field.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to show the table and index definitions, along with the query execution plan.

Comment: Please change to the `JOIN...ON` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What sometimes works in this situation is

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
 PROJECT.PROJECTID, REQUEST.REQUESTID,
 SAMPLE.SAMPLEID,SAMPLE.OTHERSAMPLEID, 
 ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2.SAMPLEID 
FROM 
 ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2,
 PROJECT,
 SAMPLE,
 REQUEST, 
 ANCESTORS A1, 
 ANCESTORS A2, 
 ANCESTORS A3 
WHERE (
 ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2.RECORDID = A1.RECORDID AND 
 A1.ANCESTORID = SAMPLE.RECORDID AND 
 SAMPLE.RECORDID = A2.RECORDID AND 
 A2.ANCESTORID = REQUEST.RECORDID AND 
 REQUEST.RECORDID = A3.RECORDID AND 
 A3.ANCESTORID = PROJECT.RECORDID) 
AND  (
 (((ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2.RecordId > 0) AND  
  ((SAMPLE.EXEMPLARSAMPLETYPE LIKE 'DNA') AND  
  (REQUEST.RecordId > 0))) 
 AND  (PROJECT.RecordId > 0))
) AS mytable 
) ORDER BY SAMPLE.RECORDID LIMIT 0,501;
```

i.e. transform your original query into a subquery within the outer `SELECT`. Then, put your `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` as subclauses of your outer `SELECT`.

This should eliminate the bottleneck with the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. The reason your query slows down with the `ORDER BY` is that the query has to retrieve all records and then SORT them - without the `ORDER BY`, the system can just spit out the first 500 records.

It is puzzling that you do have indexes on the relevant fields. If what I have suggested doesn't work, you could post the table structures and the query execution plan.

Comment: thanks Verance.  That SQL generates and error though that I have been unable to fix: "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Edited answer - that should do it!

Comment: Get error on parenthesis...

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this or do you still need help? It seems to me that you can eliminate (REQUEST.RecordId > 0))) AND  (PROJECT.RecordId > 0) since ILLUMINASEQPROTOCOL2.RecordId > 0 and the eqality condition means that the other 2 "> 0" are superfluous?